# Is there a better way to write ".then(({x}) => {return x();});"?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to directly assign a variable to a method of a returned promise. I'm wondering if theres a cleaner looking solution to this?

```
const data = ( await db.collection('x').doc('y').get(); ).data();
```

```
const data = await db.collection('x').doc('y').get().then( ({data}) => { return data(); } );
```

Comment: Well, the first one isn’t syntactically valid or equivalent to the second one – it should look like `(await db.collection('x').doc('y').get()).data`. There’s not much better than `const {data} = await db.collection('x').doc('y').get();`.

Comment: @Ry- I edited the question I made a typo, the second function returns `data()` instead of `data`, which would make them have the same result.

Comment: Then no, there’s nothing built-in better than `const data = (await db.collection('x').doc('y').get()).data();`. You can wrap that in a function if you want, though.

Comment: Question is subjective. It'd be a matter of opinion which is a better way. For example, IMO, `const data = await db.collection('x').doc('y').get().then(({ data }) => data());`.

Comment: @DrewReese agree it's subjective. But also want to point out that `(await p).method()` is not necessarily the same as `await p.then(({method}) => method())` since the `this` context will be different for both. If `method` doesn't rely on it, then they would work the same. But they aren't exactly interchangeable.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually yeah, and it's mixing Promise chains with `async/await` which is already anti-pattern, which is probably what you are pointing out. :)

Comment: @DrewReese Why is it so?

Comment: @VLAZV Yes. `await p.then(o => o.method())` would be equivalvent of the former.

Comment: @DrewReese well, not exactly. I mean, it's down to opinion. In general - yes, I agree you shouldn't mix `await` and `then`. But the purpose is mostly to reduce confusion. I'm more lax with very small usages of this. E.g., `await p.then(x => x.foo)` can work - it's short and to the point. Saves you an extra useless variable. And yes, you could do `(await p).foo` but you could also have ready made functions that handle the result, so it's better (to my eyes) to apply them as `await p.then(fn)` rather than `fn( await p )`.

Comment: Anyway, there's no getting around the fact that firestore returns a "document snapshot" which provides a data() method which provides the document data.  The question says, essentially, "I have to spill a lot of ink to get to that function, and more ink to call it.  Can I do it in less?"  The @Ry answer: "Not really, hide it in a function" is the right answer.

Comment: The OP should also know that by discarding everything but the doc data, they discard some potentially useful stuff, like doc ref, used to write changes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write

```
somePromise.then( ({x}) => x() )
```